# Include GET Variable in include(path)

Tags: php

I am trying to do an include(dirname(FILE), '/../file.php?variable=VAR'), but it is unable to find the location when I use the variable.

The directory is located one above the current one where the file is. Is it possible to pass the variables through the include?

Comment: Can you show some actual code? Why not just do `include('../file.php');`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but for what reasons you're trying to pass a query into `include`?

Comment: I'm using an HTML to PDF converter and I need to include the file processed at the specific GET var. I guess I'll just write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, though you won't need this at all, because `$_GET`'s scope is global [i.e. accessible from every script you run].

Just to be clear:

`include($path)` searches the filesystem for a resource, then processes it.

`http://somesite.com/index.php?key=value` is a URL, whose part after the `?` sign is called *query*.

Answer (score 0):

No.

By using include, you include the source code from the file as it is. I guess you want to define a function inside the included file and call it to get the result.